# How to total dynamically created fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table row that includes price, quantity and total fields. The total field is auto totaled based on what the user enters in the price and quantity.

You are able to dynamically create/remove new rows (products) within the table and each dynamicly created row will also total.

I also have a box that should total all the fields, but the issue I have is that I am not sure how to get the values of all the fields, since each time it could be different.

Right now when a row is updated it will update the variable "total" to the total of that row, and that will be displayed as well in the total box.

I thought maybe I could add the numbers to an array, but I was not sure if that would work when the row is deleted.

How can a create a function that will create a grand total of all the totals from the table?

Here it is in a JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/xntn7p5p/

Thanks

**JavaScript**

```
var counter = 1;

jQuery('a.wei-add-service-button').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    counter++;
    var newRow = jQuery('<tr><td><input type="text" class="wei-add-field description ' + counter + '"/></td><td><input type="text" class="wei-add-field quantity ' + counter + '" /></td><td><input type="text" class="wei-add-field unit-price ' + counter + '"/></td><td><input type="text" value="" name="" placeholder="$0.00" class="wei-add-field price-total ' + counter + '" id=""/></td><td><a href="#">X</a></td></tr>');
    jQuery('table.order-details').append(newRow);
});


jQuery('table.order-details').on('click','tr a',function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
jQuery(this).parents('tr').remove();
});


jQuery('table.order-details').on("keyup", "tr", function() {
    var row = jQuery(this);
    var value = jQuery( ".unit-price", row ).val();
    var value2 = jQuery( ".quantity", row ).val();
    var total = value * value2;

    var lineTotal = jQuery( ".price-total." + counter + "2", row ).val();
    testArray[counter] = total;
    var test = testArray[counter];

    var grandTotal;

    for (var i = 0; i < testArray.length; i++) {
        grandTotal += testArray[i] << 0;
    }

    jQuery( ".wei-add-field.price-total", row ).val( '$' + total.toFixed(2) );
    jQuery(".wie-add-subtotal").text( '$' + test.toFixed(2));
  });
```

**HTML**

```
<table class="order-details">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" value="" name="" placeholder="Work Description" class="wei-add-field description 1"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="" name="" placeholder="QTY" class="wei-add-field quantity 1" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="" name="" placeholder="$0.00" class="wei-add-field unit-price 1"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="" name="" placeholder="$0.00" class="wei-add-field price-total 1" id=""/></td>
        <td> </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<div class="wei-add-service"><a href="#" class="button-secondary wei-add-service-button">Add Item</a></div>

<table class="wei-add-totals">
    <tr>
        <td width="50%">Sub Total</td>
        <td width="50%" class="wie-add-subtotal"> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At each `keyup` (or other appropriate event) you want to:

1. Initialize `grandTotal`
2. Iterate through all rows each time calculating the `total` and adding it to `grandTotal`
3. Update the grandTotal element outside the loop/iteration

The code would look like so:

```
jQuery('table.order-details').on("keyup", "tr", function() {
    var grandTotal = 0;
    $(this).parent().find('tr').each(function() {
        var row = jQuery(this);
        var value = jQuery( ".unit-price", row ).val();
        var value2 = jQuery( ".quantity", row ).val();
        var total = value * value2;
        grandTotal += total;
        jQuery( ".wei-add-field.price-total", row ).val( '$' + total.toFixed(2) );
    });
    jQuery(".wie-add-subtotal").text( '$' + grandTotal.toFixed(2));
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/xntn7p5p/2/)

**Plus**, you can make further changes to refresh `grandTotal` if a row is deleted:

1. Put the the code above in a function `reCalculate` and adjust accordingly,
2. Call the function on `keyup` and when a row is deleted.

And the code would be:

```
jQuery('table.order-details').on('click','tr a',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var table = $(this).closest('table');
    jQuery(this).parents('tr').remove();
    reCalculate.call( table );
});

jQuery('table.order-details').on("keyup", "tr", reCalculate);

function reCalculate() {
    var grandTotal = 0;
    jQuery(this).closest('table').find('tr').each(function() {
    .....
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/xntn7p5p/3/)

Comment: When trying to add the reCalculate function, Is there any syntax or issues with JQuery that would cause issues? When I change the line "jQuery(this).closest('table').find('tr').each(function() {" it outputs NAN. It is working great on JSFiddle, but when I move it to WordPress the output does not seem to work. :-( Thanks, your solution for adding worked charms! Ill be sure to reward your question!

Comment: On the actual working site, I actually have a <thead> row that seems to be effecting it. I removed that and it seems to also work on WordPress

Comment: Not sure I quite got what's causing the `NaN` error on your first comment -- JavaScript is simply saying that what you're trying to parse is not a number. ... Good that you're using `thead`. I am guessing that you also had `tbody`, right? All you need to do is to replace all `table` occurrences in my code with `tbody`. That should do it. Let us know how that goes.